# PLESK - 8443 - disable admin access for domain

Tags: plesk

It is possible to denied for one selected domain the access to example.com:8443 ?
I have two domain's in Plesk. I want that the example.com:8443 has no access to the admin plesk control panel.
So that the 8443 port is not reachable for this domain.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [not implemented in Plesk yet](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000919233).
You can suggest this feature at https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions

The top-ranked suggestions are likely to be included in the next versions of Plesk.

The only possibility at the moment is if a domain is behind CloudFlare. In this case, it is possible to [block proxying all ports except 80 and 443](https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2015/05/block-ports-cloudflare/) on the CloudFlare side.

Comment: Yea that is true.